# Use existing document formatter in VS.code

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Is there anyway to use an existing document formatter for a newly created language within VS.code?

I'm creating a new language extension but currently it doesn't support document formatting. However when I treat the document as C# the formating works fine. So in other words I want my new language to use the C# document formatter instead of reinventing the wheel.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Same question here 4 years later for custom YAML extension. Found no solution until now.